How to set env variable from another one set at build time
I would like to set a variable (say A) from the value of another variable that is only known at build time, for instance HOME:
FROM ubuntu
RUN export A=$HOME/file.txt

Then:
docker build -t mubuntu -< ./ubuntu.Dockerfile

The problem is the export command does not seem to export anything in A. and when I print the value of A in my container:
docker run -ti mubuntu printenv A

I see A is empty
The problem is that I need this env variable to correctly install my programs in the container at buildtime (installation looks explicitly for my A variable) and to run them.
I don't want to hard code it anywhere because it may change.
How can I work around it?

Does the recipe in Set dynamic ENV in Dockerfile (and I can modify the Dockerfile only) address your needs?  You can't set ENV to the result of a command, and RUN export does nothing, so your options are somewhat limited.  Many questions in this space focus on path-like variables, and one legitimate option is to say that the path in the container filesystem is in fact fixed.
